# OpenMP Location of Private Variables?

Tags: openmp

Where do openmp private variables get allocated? On each thread stack, dynamically or through some shared array or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenMP specification doesn't specify if those variables are to be allocated on the stack or on the heap (and if they are on the heap if it is in a shared array or if there is one object allocated for each thread). Generally I would assume that private variables are allocated on the stack (there is no reason not to and it's generally more efficient). According to [the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp.pdf) that is the behaviour used in libgomp (the implemention used by gcc) at least, no clue about other implemantations though (although I see little reason why those shouldn't do the same thing).

Comment: Makes sense, that is what I would have thought. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP does not specify anything about the allocation of private variables. 
There are two options : heap and stack. 
If we think about each thread executing less number of instructions, it makes sense for the master thread to allocate private variables like below.

Code :

```
1: set_threads(n)
2: #pragma omp parallel private(var)
3: { 
4:   var = ...
5:}
```

Machine code : 
line2 :  var_ptr = new variables[n] 
line4:   var_ptr[get_thread_id()] =  ...

But the above code will induce a lot of false-sharing among the private variables in different threads. So I think it would make sense for the compiler to allocate them on the stack of each thread.

Comment: Do you have any references for this? The specification doesn't seem to specify that and it does seem inefficient compared to simply allocating on the stack. Furthermore according to [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp.pdf) at least libgomp doesn't do it like that. Besides what directives are there to avoid deallocating `private` data, there doesn't seem to be any at least.

Comment: Shared != private and the pseudo-code you showed is certainly completely wrong since this code provokes false sharing which is a major performance killer on most (= cache coherent) CPU architectures.

Comment: @above .. oh yeah dude .. i got your point now. The problem is that i was thinking from a developers perspective of minimizing the number of instructions executed. allocating private variables on heap would ensure that only master thread does a malloc compared to every thread decrementing stack pointer to accommodate the private variable. but this would surely induce false sharing among private variables in the longer run. Thanks for pointing it out. PS: please look at the edited post.

Comment: @prathmesh.kallurkar: There is still a problem in your logic. Decrementing the stackpointer is extremely cheap, while malloc is anything but. I don't know the exact numbers, but I would estimate malloc at >100 clock cycles, while stack allocation is likely to be at 1 cycle (not counting initialization in either case), which is probably hidden somewhere in the pipeline anyways (and might be necessary either way). So even discounting false sharing stack allocation is very likely to be cheaper

Comment: @grizzly that was just a notional cost i was taking about ... ya surely one malloc is costlier than esp=esp-4 sort of thing.

Comment: @Grizzly thread_private construct maintains the value of private variables across parallel regions .. this would be possible only of their location was not de-allocated after the end of first parallel block.